# How can I fetch only the unique values of column 2 based on column 1 values?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
admin_id  |  country_id
-------------------------
   5            44
   5            32
   3            2
   92           32
   92           30
   5            30
```

I want to fetch all `country_id` values if `admin_id` `$_Session['admin']['id'] = 5` AND all the `country_id` values if `admin_id = 92`.

There can be duplicates because many admins can have the same `country_id`, so in that case I want to keep ONLY the `country_id` of the `admin_id=92`

The desired output:

```
admin_id  |  country_id
-------------------------
   5            44             
   92           32
   92           30
```

**Further explanation:**

As you can see `admin_id=3` is excluded because I just dont want that one and whenever there is duplicate `country_id` between `admin_id = 92` and `$_Session['admin']['id'] = 5`, I keep the row with `admin_id = 92` .

Comment: This sentence is still raising more questions, then giving info: "BUT I dont want duplicate country_id . Whenever there are duplicate (which will almost always be the case) country_id then take only the one where admin_id was 3."   Please change it so it becomes clear

Comment: @Luuk thanks, I just re formulated that.

Comment: It is still not clear. Whyt is admin_id=3 not in the output?  Why does admin_id=5 have country_id=44 ? (and not country_id=32 or 30 ?)

Comment: @Luuk I dont want the row with `admin_id=3`. Why does admin_id=5 have country_id=44 ? thats because `admin_id=92` has the same value so I keep this row instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
   admin_id,
   CASE WHEN COUNT(country_id) > 1
     THEN (select country_id from mytable WHERE admin_id=92)
     ELSE MAX(country_id) END as country_id
FROM 
   mytable
GROUP BY 
   admin_id;
```

I am assuming that there is only 1 country for admin_id=92.

output of above:

```
+----------+-------------------+------------+
| admin_id | COUNT(country_id) | country_id |
+----------+-------------------+------------+
|        5 |                 2 |         32 |
|        3 |                 1 |          2 |
|       92 |                 1 |         32 |
+----------+-------------------+------------+
```

BTW, it is unclear why admin_3=3 is not in your desired output.

EDIT: after the question changed a couple of times... :

```
SELECT
  admin_id,
  country_id
FROM 
  mytable
WHERE admin_id=92
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  admin_id,
  country_id
FROM 
  mytable
WHERE admin_id<>92 
  AND NOT country_id IN (SELECT country_id FROM mytable WHERE admin_id=92)
  AND admin_id<>3;
```

output:

```
+----------+------------+
| admin_id | country_id |
+----------+------------+
|       92 |         32 |
|       92 |         30 |
|        5 |         44 |
+----------+------------+
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately there can be many countries for admin_id=92 as well. Its a quiet confusing task for me as well.

Comment: I basically want to keep the ones of `admin_id=92` and the rest of `$_Session['admin']['id'] = 5` (some of them can be the same so I just want to keep the ones of `admin_id=92`).

Comment: Please rephrase your question when your question is clear to you ... 

Comment: I just did, check the desired output for a better understanding. I dont want the row with admin_id=3 . Read my question. I just want the ones with `admin_id=92` and `$_Session['admin']['id'] = 5`

Comment: thank you! One last thing, how about joining another table to this query? I tried but it fails

Comment: DOING THIS FAILS: `SELECT * FROM parking_admins_countries_relation         
        WHERE parking_admins_countries_relation.admin_id=? UNION ALL 
        SELECT * FROM parking_admins_countries_relation 
        JOIN parking_countries ON parking_admins_countries_relation.country_id=parking_countries.id
        WHERE admin_id<>? AND NOT country_id IN (SELECT country_id FROM parking_admins_countries_relation WHERE admin_id=?) AND admin_id<>?;`

Comment: This is a complete other statement than the one i suggested, so i will not comment on this. (you should not put SQL statement in a comment on SO )

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to exclude rows of `admin_id = 5` with `country_id` that exist in rows of `admin_id = 92`:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where t.admin_id = 92 
   or (
     t.admin_id = 5
     and 
     not exists (select 1 from tablename where admin_id = 92 and country_id = t.country_id)
   )
```

For MySql 8.0+ you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select admin_id, country_id
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by country_id order by admin_id = 92 desc) rn 
  from tablename
  where admin_id in (5, 92)
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2fbd9d41cb32d14f613bacad9d54e700).
Results:

```
> admin_id | country_id
> -------: | ---------:
>        5 |         44
>       92 |         32
>       92 |         30
```

Comment: thanks but which do you suggest is better, yours or the one below?

Comment: @ssssss try them in your actual data.